# Download with resume

Tags: php, download, resume

I've searched **many** topics and posts and made my own downloading snippet with *2 functions* as below!

Download starts with no problem, custom errors are shown when user hasn't enough credit, all things are right but the resume! I thought it maybe Headers, but I didn't miss them.

I read many posts on stackoverflow too.

Helps needed!

```
function readfile_chunked($filename, $size = '', $uid, $pid, $retbytes = TRUE)
{
    global $each_download;
    $chunk_size = 1024*1024;
    $buffer = '';
    $cnt =0;
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
    if ($handle === false)
    {
        return false;
    }
        //check if http_range is sent by browser (or download manager)
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
    {
        list($a, $range)=explode("=",$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']);
        str_replace($range, "-", $range);
        $size2=$size-1;
        $new_length=$size2-$range;
        header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content");
        header("Content-Length: $new_length");
        header("Content-Range: bytes $range$size2/$size");
        fseek($fp,$range);
    }
    else
    {
        if(get_user_meta($uid, 'revo_dropped', true) != $pid)
        {
            update_user_meta($uid, 'dropped', $pid);
            update_user_meta($uid, 'credits', get_user_meta($uid, 'credits', true)-$each_download);
        }
        $size2 = $size-1; 
        header("Content-Range: bytes 0-$size2/$size");
        header("Content-Length: ".$size);
    }
    while (!feof($handle) && connection_status()==0)
    {
        @set_time_limit(0);
        $buffer = fread($handle, $chunk_size);
        echo $buffer;
        ob_flush();
        flush();
        if ($retbytes)
        {
            $cnt += strlen($buffer);
        }
    }
    $status = fclose($handle);
    if ($retbytes && $status)
    {
        return $cnt;
    }
    return $status;
}
function save_file()
{
    global $wpdb;
    global $uid;
    global $each_download;
    $hash = @$_GET["download"];
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
    set_time_limit(0);
    session_cache_limiter('none');
    set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);
    if(preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]{32}$/i',$hash))
    {
        if($row = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM wp_dlurl WHERE hash = '{$hash}'",ARRAY_A))
        {
            if(is_user_logged_in())
            {
                if($row['price'] != 0)
                    $each_download = $row['price'];
                if(get_user_meta($uid, 'credits', true) >= $each_download)
                {
                    $parts = pathinfo($row['url']);
                    $url = $parts['dirname'] . '/' . $parts['basename'];//urlencode($parts['basename']);
                    $file = pathinfo($row['filename']);
                    $ext = $file['extension'];

                    /* List of File Types */ 
                    $fileTypes['swf'] = 'application/x-shockwave-flash';
                    $fileTypes['pdf'] = 'application/pdf';
                    $fileTypes['exe'] = 'application/octet-stream';
                    $fileTypes['zip'] = 'application/zip';
                    $fileTypes['doc'] = 'application/msword';
                    $fileTypes['xls'] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
                    $fileTypes['ppt'] = 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint';
                    $fileTypes['gif'] = 'image/gif';
                    $fileTypes['png'] = 'image/png';
                    $fileTypes['jpeg'] = 'image/jpg';
                    $fileTypes['jpg'] = 'image/jpg';
                    $fileTypes['rar'] = 'application/rar';
                    $fileTypes['ra'] = 'audio/x-pn-realaudio';
                    $fileTypes['ram'] = 'audio/x-pn-realaudio';
                    $fileTypes['ogg'] = 'audio/x-pn-realaudio';
                    $fileTypes['wav'] = 'video/x-msvideo';
                    $fileTypes['wmv'] = 'video/x-msvideo';
                    $fileTypes['avi'] = 'video/x-msvideo';
                    $fileTypes['asf'] = 'video/x-msvideo';
                    $fileTypes['divx'] = 'video/x-msvideo';
                    $fileTypes['mp3'] = 'audio/mpeg';
                    $fileTypes['mp4'] = 'audio/mpeg';
                    $fileTypes['mpeg'] = 'video/mpeg';
                    $fileTypes['mpg'] = 'video/mpeg';
                    $fileTypes['mpe'] = 'video/mpeg';
                    $fileTypes['mov'] = 'video/quicktime';
                    $fileTypes['swf'] = 'video/quicktime';
                    $fileTypes['3gp'] = 'video/quicktime';
                    $fileTypes['m4a'] = 'video/quicktime';
                    $fileTypes['aac'] = 'video/quicktime';
                    $fileTypes['m3u'] = 'video/quicktime';
                    $contentType = $fileTypes[$ext];
                    //ob_end_clean();
                    ob_start();
                    header("Pragma: public");
                    header("Expires: 0");
                    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
                    header("Cache-Control: public");
                    header("Robots: none");
                    header("Content-Type: ".$contentType."");
                    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
                    $new_name = $row['filename'];//rand(1000,999999).".".$ext;
                    $contentDisposition = 'attachment';
                    if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "MSIE"))
                    {
                        $new_name = preg_replace('/\./', '%2e', $new_name, substr_count($new_name,'.') - 1);
                    }
                    $new_name = urlencode($new_name);
                    //@ob_end_clean();
                    header("Content-Disposition: ".$contentDisposition."; filename=\"".$new_name."\";");
                    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
                    header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
                    $size = $row['size'];
                    $thefile = $url;

                    $urlparsed = parse_url($thefile); // urlllllllllllll
                    $isURI = array_key_exists('scheme', $urlparsed);
                    $localURI = (bool) strstr($thefile, get_bloginfo('wpurl')); 
                    $patterns = array( '|^'. get_bloginfo('wpurl') . '/' . '|');
                    $path = preg_replace( $patterns, '', $thefile );
                    // this is joining the ABSPATH constant, changing any slashes to local filesystem slashes, and then finally getting the real path.
                    $thefile = str_replace( '/', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, path_join( ABSPATH, $path ) );

                    ///////////////////////////////////
                    if($size == 0)
                    {
                        showMessage('Size 0');
                    } 
                    if (isset($size) && $size > 0)
                    {
                        //header("Content-Length: ".$size);
                        @readfile_chunked($thefile, $size, $uid, $pid);
                    }
                    ///////////////////////////////////
                    exit;
                }
                else
                    showMessage("buy credit");
            }
            else
                showMessage("login");
        }
        else
        {
            wp_redirect(get_bloginfo('url'));
            exit;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        wp_redirect(get_bloginfo('url'));
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see a lot of error suppressing, a wall of code and the notion by you of "errors shown on their situation but with no resume". Is this a quest?

Comment: searching for the precious can make one go crazy

Comment: Consider choosing a library to offer partial downloads, e.g. http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.http.http-download.intro.php

Answer (score 4):

This script might help you out:

```
<?php 
/**
 * Copyright 2012 Armand Niculescu - media-division.com
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
 * 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 * 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE FREEBSD PROJECT "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE FREEBSD PROJECT OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */
// get the file request, throw error if nothing supplied

// hide notices
@ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE);

//- turn off compression on the server
@apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

if(!isset($_REQUEST['file']) || empty($_REQUEST['file'])) 
{
    header("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request");
    exit;
}

// sanitize the file request, keep just the name and extension
// also, replaces the file location with a preset one ('./myfiles/' in this example)
$file_path  = $_REQUEST['file'];
$path_parts = pathinfo($file_path);
$file_name  = $path_parts['basename'];
$file_ext   = $path_parts['extension'];
$file_path  = './myfiles/' . $file_name;

// allow a file to be streamed instead of sent as an attachment
$is_attachment = isset($_REQUEST['stream']) ? false : true;

// make sure the file exists
if (is_file($file_path))
{
    $file_size  = filesize($file_path);
    $file = @fopen($file_path,"rb");
    if ($file)
    {
        // set the headers, prevent caching
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: -1");
        header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"");

        // set appropriate headers for attachment or streamed file
        if ($is_attachment)
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"");
        else
                header('Content-Disposition: inline;');

        // set the mime type based on extension, add yours if needed.
        $ctype_default = "application/octet-stream";
        $content_types = array(
                "exe" =--> "application/octet-stream",
                "zip" => "application/zip",
                "mp3" => "audio/mpeg",
                "mpg" => "video/mpeg",
                "avi" => "video/x-msvideo",
        );
        $ctype = isset($content_types[$file_ext]) ? $content_types[$file_ext] : $ctype_default;
        header("Content-Type: " . $ctype);

        //check if http_range is sent by browser (or download manager)
        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
        {
            list($size_unit, $range_orig) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
            if ($size_unit == 'bytes')
            {
                //multiple ranges could be specified at the same time, but for simplicity only serve the first range
                //http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-http-range-retrieval-00.txt
                list($range, $extra_ranges) = explode(',', $range_orig, 2);
            }
            else
            {
                $range = '';
                header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
                exit;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $range = '';
        }

        //figure out download piece from range (if set)
        list($seek_start, $seek_end) = explode('-', $range, 2);

        //set start and end based on range (if set), else set defaults
        //also check for invalid ranges.
        $seek_end   = (empty($seek_end)) ? ($file_size - 1) : min(abs(intval($seek_end)),($file_size - 1));
        $seek_start = (empty($seek_start) || $seek_end < abs(intval($seek_start))) ? 0 : max(abs(intval($seek_start)),0);

        //Only send partial content header if downloading a piece of the file (IE workaround)
        if ($seek_start > 0 || $seek_end < ($file_size - 1))
        {
            header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
            header('Content-Range: bytes '.$seek_start.'-'.$seek_end.'/'.$file_size);
            header('Content-Length: '.($seek_end - $seek_start + 1));
        }
        else
          header("Content-Length: $file_size");

        header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

        set_time_limit(0);
        fseek($file, $seek_start);

        while(!feof($file)) 
        {
            print(@fread($file, 1024*8));
            ob_flush();
            flush();
            if (connection_status()!=0) 
            {
                @fclose($file);
                exit;
            }           
        }

        // file save was a success
        @fclose($file);
        exit;
    }
    else 
    {
        // file couldn't be opened
        header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
        exit;
    }
}
else
{
    // file does not exist
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    exit;
}
```

Taken from:
http://www.richnetapps.com/php-download-script-with-resume-option/